# What patterns are generally interesting to look at to handle validation?

Tags: c#, validation, design-patterns

I'm creating an sudoku in c#.

A user can create an new sudoku.
My sudoku class:

```
public class Sudoku
{
    #region Datamembers

    private Field[,] grid;
    private byte blockRows;
    private byte blockColumns;
    private Hashtable peers;
```

The user can save the newly created sudoku. When doing so, some validations are performed. For example: Look if not all fields are filled, look if not all fields are empty, look if no identical digits in same row, column, block, ...

My validation ends up looking like this: (it is situated in the sudoku class)

```
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        bool isValidSetup = this.IsValidSetup();
        if (!isValidSetup) return isValidSetup;

        return this.IsTrulyValid();
    }

    private bool IsValidSetup()
    {
        bool isEntirelyFilled = this.Is_EntirelyFilled();
        bool isEntirelyEmpty = this.Is_EntirelyEmpty();
        bool hasIdenticalDigits = this.Has_IdenticalDigits();

        this.Add_SetupValidationMessages(isEntirelyFilled, isEntirelyEmpty, hasIdenticalDigits);

        return !isEntirelyEmpty && !isEntirelyFilled && !hasIdenticalDigits;
    }

    private bool IsTrulyValid()
    {
        this.Clean();
        this.Solve();
        bool hasNoSolutions = !this.Is_EntirelyFilled();

        bool hasMultipleSolutions = false;
        if (!hasNoSolutions) hasMultipleSolutions = this.Has_MultipleSolutions();

        this.Add_TrulyValidationMessages(hasNoSolutions, hasMultipleSolutions);

        return !hasNoSolutions && !hasMultipleSolutions;
    }
```

I would like to split validation from sudoku, to make it OOP.

I looked into the strategy pattern, since that looked like something I could use, and is used a lot in validation. But as far as I understand the pattern, it's not what I need after all; Reason for that is because it's based on selecting a validation based on certain factors. I'm probably wrong, but I can't seem to realize why I would need that in my situation.

I Need one of the seperated validations (Is_EntirelyFilled() ) in another class. That's the only one not only used to validate the sudoku.
So, should I just put all this validation in 1 class? Or should make separate classes for each validation and call them seperatly? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I do not know sudoku game but I think you should use Strategy because My Instructor gave me Sudoku example while I was attending software design patterns course.

Comment: You should have a ValidationHandle as Abstract Implement it differently for your needs and pass it to your client code. Something like that as I remember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a ValidationHandle as Abstract Implement it differently for your needs and pass it to your client code. Something like that as I remember.

The IBrakeBehaveior should be your IValidationHandle
The sub ones are validation types.

Car is the cllient class  and you need an instance of IValidationHandle in client code.
Where you need in client code you call IValidationHandleInstance.Validate()
by polymorphism it knows how validation execute.

[image]

Something like that

```
     public interface IValidationHandle 
     {
       bool Validate();         
     }

      //TODOs: Separate classes
      public class IsTrulyValidValidator:IValidationHandle;
      public class IsValidValitor:IValidationHandle;
      public class EntirelyFilledValidator:IValidationHandle;

      class Client
      {
           private IValidationHandle validator=null;
           public void SetValidationHandler(IValidationHandle validator)
           {
             this.validator=validator;
           }
            //Where You need call
            validator.Validate();
       }
```

Comment: I have this now indeed. I just found it kinda strange to have all these separated classes 'IdenticalDigits', 'EntirelyFilled', .. So Thanks, will implement it like this after all!

Comment: Yes, well; I still need to create seperate classes  'IdenticalDigits', 'EntirelyFilled', .. that implements IValidate interface, right? The IsTrulyValid and isSetup valid where unnecessary replacements to create a kinda 'logical' encapsulation.

Comment: If you do not separate files it starts to look like Façade. Façade is commonly using for providing API's and hiding messy codes. So separation seems better for reuse.